# phonegap - should navigator work in the browser?

Tags: cordova

I'm just trying to get phonegap/cordova working. Should the Navigator's function be working in the android emulator? When i do the geolocation getcurrentposition function, it doesn't do anything.

When i try the navigator.notification.alert() in the browser and emulator, it doesn't work. It says that navigator.notification.alert() isn't defined.

I have no idea what the problem is. I would have figured it would have at least shown a browser alert.

My manifest is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.timetracker2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.timetracker2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
            <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The geolocation api does not work in the emulator unless you enable high accuracy. It sounds like you are either not waiting for the "deviceready" event or haven't referenced the cordova.js file correctly.

Comment: hey i read your blog! i'm calling it on an onclick event. Nothing is happening though. I ran in it with the ripple emulator and it worked. I'm not sure i have the cordova jar file and manifest set up. The navigator.notification.alert() function works in the android emulator though.

Comment: i abandoned that project and tried to run the exampleCordova app and i think i'm running into the same issue. I can't get past the Device is Ready screen with the example app. I posted a new question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804533/phonegap-2-2-0-cant-get-past-the-device-is-ready-screen-on-android . What code do you need to see?