# phonegap 2.2.0 can't get past the "Device is Ready" screen on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have just downloaded the latest(2.2.0) phonegap package and am trying to run the exampleCordava app that comes with it. The app will never get past the "Device is Ready" splash screen with the cordova cube logo.

I've tried deploying it to emulators with Android 2.2, 4.0.3, and 4.1.2 with the same result. All of them use an Intel Atom (x86) CPU.

I get the following errors/warnings/messages in LogCat

sqlite returned: error code => 14, msg = cannot open file at 27 .... in webview.db

call to OpenGL ES API  with no current context(logged once per thread)

I noticed that in older phonegap/cordova versions you had to manually add the cordova jar file to the build path. That wasn't in the build path in the exampleCordova app. I tried adding it to the build path and it still didn't work. Got the same result.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: If there is a green flashing "Device is Ready" under the PG bot logo then you have successfully got PhoneGap working.

Comment: oh. I thought the example app had a list of different buttons that triggered different actions? That's what i've been seeing in tutorial videos. Has that been done away with in the latest release? You can see what i'm referring to here -> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCMXQGS_w&t=8m56s

Comment: Yup, that is the old sample app. That was deprecated out awhile back.

Comment: gotcha thanks! I was so confused. I noticed that there's a lot of functions in that main.js file but I couldn't find where those were being called and i was watching that youtube video with that old app. I was sitting there staring at "Device is Ready" just waiting for something to happen that would indicate phonegap is working correctly. I figured there was more to the example app. Anyways, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the kitchensink app does not come with the latest phonegap package. If you're seeing "Device is Ready", cordova is successfully working.